# Anaconda-Navigator problem loading packages

Tags: anaconda

I am currently on Windows 11 and facing this problem since upgrade. Each time I install anaconda-navigator, on first time opening it runs smoothly however on second time if I open from windows, it opens but gets stuck on environment loading and when I open it from prompt, I get the error below. I do realize that error is from conda-script.py line587 however I don't want to do modifications blindly so need some expert opinion on how to resolve it.
I never faced these issues even on last moment on Windows 10, and I don't know how much windows upgrade is a problem here.

```
(base) C:\Users\abdul>anaconda-navigator
2021-10-20 19:51:06,740 - ERROR anaconda_api._pip_data_ready:579
C:/Users/abdul/anaconda3/python.exe C:/Users/abdul/anaconda3/Scripts/conda-script.py list --json: Not a conda environment: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 587, in _pip_data_ready
    channel_urls = set(package['base_url'] for package in output if package['platform'] != 'pypi')
  File "C:\Users\abdul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 587, in <genexpr>
    channel_urls = set(package['base_url'] for package in output if package['platform'] != 'pypi')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```